# Will it be wise to use pirated copy of the Win XP even when its licensing has ended.?

Tags: windows-xp

I have a software that runs only on Windows XP and I had like to use it as it is. And Microsoft has ended the support and I need to use Win XP though I cant buy it obviously because MS doesn't sell it anymore. So will it be wise to use pirated copy of the same even if licensing has ended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like it's your only option. Just be very careful as there are no security update at all, and with so many computers still on XP, I'm sure there are quite a few virus floating around.

Perhaps install it on a virtual machine if it's not a program that needs to much diskspace or RAM just to keep you more secure.